# Collections Counter module issue with most_common class

Tags: python

I have a dictionary made from a List called ltst3_upper, and now I am trying to use the class most_common to get only the top 10 key:values with the below code:

```
result3  = Counter(list3_upper).most_common(10)
sort_result3 = OrderedDict(sorted(result3.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

I am lopping this code in several Lists which are 'organized' with Counter, and some of them have more than 10 keys:values, so I want to trim the Dict.

Ps. as you can see besides the top 10 values I am also ordering the from highest to smallest, but i dont think the problem is there.

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Is this happening because some Lists do not have 10 keys:values?

Thanks a lot for any input you might have.

Comment: 1. `most_common` is a method, not a class. 2. `result3` is a list. `list` objects don't have an `items()` method, so `result3.items()` fails. 3. You want to sort, but then you try to create a dictionary. It is not clear what you are attempting to achieve. You should provide some example input and expected output.

Comment: use `OrderedDict(sorted(result3, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))`..

Comment: There is absolutely no need for `sorted`, as the result of `most_common` is _already_ sorted. Just do `OrderedDict(result3)`

Comment: But later I will need to export to a csv, and in such case the values are nor sorted.. i guess. Its just sorted if printed.. am i right?

Comment: No, the result of `most_common` is a list, which is sorted always the same way. Documentation says "...from the most common to the least". If they end up in a different order in your CSV, the poblem must be someplace else. `sorted` does not do anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As the documentation states,](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)`most_common` returns a list of the most common elements.  `.items` is a `dict` method - lists don't have items.  If you want to do something to all members in the list, you'd iterate over them..:

```
for result in result3:
    o = OrderedDict(sorted(result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

**but** this won't work either -  the individual members of the list are `tuple`, not `dict` - and `tuple` objects don't have an `items` method. Instead, just create the `OrderedDict` with `result`:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
import operator

list3_upper = ['a', 'e', 'a']

result3  = Counter(list3_upper).most_common(10)

result_dict = OrderedDict(result3)
print(result_dict)
>>> OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('e', 1)])
```

Comment: it makes sense... I am understanding now. Thanks!

Comment: You also have to remove the `key` and `reverse` parameters, which belonged to `sorted`.Now it will add those as entries to the resulting dictionary!